# Where can I find information about this deletion?

Tags: genetics

Consider the following chromosomal formula

> 46,XX,del(7)(q11q36)[12]/46,XX[13]

It indicates that the patient has 46 chromosomes, is a female and has a deletion on the long arm of chromosome 7 spanning the bands from 11 to 36.

**Where can I find medical information about this specific deletion?**

Of course, I am interested in the health impact of this deletion and not about a list of gene names.